# React / JS function fails first time after refresh - then works

Tags: javascript, react-native

*I added useEffect to the xml processing function and it fixed it right up.*

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (inputValue.length > 50) {
            setXmlValue((xmlValue) => loadPoBXml(inputValue));  
        }             
    }, [inputValue])
```

I am rather stumped with this problem.
I am writing a web app that converts a base64 string into a xml file and extracts data from that xml file.

When I first run the app after a `npm start` or after a browser refresh the function that converts the string does not complete correctly. If I trigger the function a second time, it works, and will continue to work until I do a refresh. I believe the problem lies within the `populateData` function and have tried to make it work as async, but that made the problem considerably worse.

I have included a screenshot of my console log and the code is detailed below (please note I have for brevity removed some parts of the code):

```
Buffer.from('anything','base64');


export default function Home() {
    // State to store value from the input field
    const [xmlValue, setXmlValue] = useState([]);
    const [buildValue, setBuildValue] = useState([]);
    const [buildData, setBuildData] = useState([]);
    const [mainSkill, setMainSkill] = useState("");
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

    const xmlData = useSelector(state => state)

    // redux data management     
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

     function populateData(str) {
        let data = ""
        if (str.includes("https://")) {
            data = httpGet(str)
        }
        else {
            data = str
        }
        
        if(typeof xmlData !== "unknown") {
            console.log("decode was called")
            
            // get xml data as an array
            console.log("pob data was called")
            setXmlValue((xmlValue) => loadPoBXml(data))
                                    
            // populate character data
            console.log("handle character called")

            handleChar(xmlValue)

            
            // find the main dps skill
            findMainSkill(xmlValue)

            // populate the store
            dispatch(populateGems(xmlValue))
            console.log("store loaded")
        }
        else {
            console.log("no decode called")
            handleChar(xmlData)
            findMainSkill(xmlData) 
        }             
    }

    function findMainSkill(event) {
        // removed code      
    };

    function populateBuildData(data) {                
        //removed code        
    }

    function handleChar(event) {
        console.log(event)
        let temp = event.getElementsByTagName('Build')
        setBuildValue((buildValue) => temp);
        populateBuildData(temp)                
    };

    // Input Field handler
    const handleUserInput = (e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
    };

    // Reset Input Field handler
    const resetInputField = () => {   
        setInputValue("");
        setBuildValue([])
        setBuildData([])       
    };
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="InsideContent">                     
                <Input className="input1"
                placeholder="Paste PoB Code"
                name="pobCode" 
                value={inputValue} 
                onChange={handleUserInput} />
            </div>

            <div className="InsideContent"> 
                <Button1 onClick={() => populateData(inputValue)}>Confirm</Button1>                
                <Button2 onClick={resetInputField}>Reset</Button2>
            </div>

            
            {buildValue.length > 0 && (
                <div className="card">
                <div className="divider"></div>
                    {buildValue.map((item, i) => (
                    <ul key={`item${i}`}>
                        <div className="acend">
                            <img src={require("../images/" + item.attributes.ascendClassName +".png")}></img>                      
                        </div>
                        <div className="leftInfo">
                            <p>{item.attributes.ascendClassName} Level: {item.attributes.level}</p>                                                    
                            <div className="leftInfoSmall">
                                <p>{mainSkill}&emsp;{buildData.CombinedDPS} DPS</p>
                                <p>Life: <span className="redText">{buildData.Life}</span>&ensp;ES: <span className="blueText">{buildData.EnergyShield}</span>&ensp;Ward: <span className="grayText">{buildData.Ward}</span></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="rightInfo">
                            <p>EHP: {buildData.TotalEHP}&ensp;Max Hit: {buildData.SecondMinimalMaximumHitTaken == 0 ? buildData.PhysicalMaximumHitTaken : buildData.SecondMinimalMaximumHitTaken}</p>
                            <p>Phy Reduction: {buildData.PhysicalDamageReduction}%&ensp;Evasion: {buildData.MeleeEvadeChance}%&ensp;Spell Supression: {buildData.SpellSuppressionChance}%</p>
                            <p>Resistances: <span className="redText">{buildData.FireResist}</span>/<span className="blueText">{buildData.ColdResist}</span>/<span className="yellowText">{buildData.LightningResist}</span>/<span className="purpleText">{buildData.ChaosResist}</span></p>
                        </div>                                                                                             
                    </ul>
                    ))}
                </div>
                
            )}
        </>
    )
}

function loadPoBXml(str) {
    var res = decodePoBString(str);
    var xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(res);
    console.log("pob data was loaded")
    return xml
}

function decodePoBString(str) {
    return inflateSync(new Buffer(str, "base64")).toString()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using ```useeffect``` hook to run the conversion on the first start ?, You can call an async function with that hook and await for the results.

Comment: I did try but I may have implemented it wrong. Where should I use the useEffect?

Comment: Imho you're doing too much in that function, break it down more and use useCallback and/or useEffect to have dependencies. You're setting xmlValue and using it at the same time, that can't work, the dataflow is wrong.

Comment: Okay thank mttetc I will try that too.

Comment: This can give you a good start, using async with useeffect -> https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-pine-i21ovp

Comment: useEffect seems to have done the trick. I guess it was too much for one function.

Comment: Maybe you can add solved in the top of the answer, Or do you want any of us to put nin a detailed answer regarding it ?